# How can I extract the XY points of the contours from a Plotly contour plot?

Tags: python, plotly, contour, plotly-python

I would like to use the contour plots it generates to quantify features in my images. Plotly doesn't provide details of how contours are calculated. Can anyone tell me how to extract that information from this basic example?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data =
    go.Contour(
        z=[[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
           [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
           [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
           [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
           [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]]
    ))
fig.show()
```